# Task that completes on event

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I am trying to write a C# method that returns a task. The task should register to an event on another object (that I did not write and do not control) and complete when the event is triggered. The event args contain the result of the task.

I have tried the following idea (which is bad...):

```
public Task<int> GetValue(ObjectToWaitFor waitFor)
{
    var flag = false;
    int value = -1;

    return Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => 
    {
        waitFor.TheEvent += (s, e) =>
        {
            value = e.Value;
            flag = true;
        };
        while (!flag)
        {
            Task.Delay(100).Wait();
        }

        return value;
    });
}
```

using a flag, which is set to true on the event handler, and then have the task loop until the flag is set to true. But it does not seem like an elegant solution and I wonder if there is some better way.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have updated the question with the code that I am trying to replace with a better solution. I simply did not feel it was necessary to include a "worse practice" example in a question that asks for a best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @jonskeet 's answer:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    //type parameter here defines the type of the Task
    //so here, we're expecting to make a Task<int>
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    foo.Evt += (sender, eventArgs) => {
        tcs.SetResult(0);
        //or tcs.SetException(someException);
        //etc...
    };
    //here's your task, ready to go.
    Task<int> task = tcs.Task;
}
class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Evt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're looking for [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174). Basically, you create one of those (and remember it), and hand back the task that it provides in the `Task` property.

When the event is triggered, set the appropriate result/fault on the completion source, and you're done.